# Angular library retro-compatibility

Tags: angular

I have made an library in Angular 13, but I have noticed that it's not work with previous Angular versions. There is a method for retro compatibility or need to create a library version for each Angular one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have updated the library to Angular 13 it can be used by Angular 13 apps only.